# How to elegantly sum up nullable and retain null when all null

Tags: c#, sum, nullable

Say I have this property:

```
public double? MyTotal
{
    get
    {
        return (new double?[] {
            Value1,
            Value2,
            Value3
        }).Sum();
    }
}
```

where `Value1`, `Value2`, and `Value3` are nullable doubles `double?`.

How can I make sure that `MyTotal` returns `null` when `Value1`, `Value2`, and `Value3` are all `null`?

The above property works fine when say `Value1` is `100.0` and the rest are `null` - it returns `100.0`, but I need to differentiate between nulls and 0s.

Comment: Yes this is C#, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient but probably the most elegant.

```
double?[] vars =
{
    null,
    null,
    null
};
vars.Any(d => d.HasValue) ? vars.Sum() : null
```